# Differenziate a matricial expression

Tags: matrices, analysis, numerical-methods, jacobian

I'm stuck on this problem about differentiating an expression with matrices.

The expression it's the following: $F(u)= (D_1 * \vec{u})*(I\vec{u})$, where $I$ is the identity, $\vec{u}$ is a vector of length $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$

To find the jacobian matrix $JF(u)$, applicated to a vector $v$, I have to solve this limit:

$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(\vec{u} +\epsilon \vec{v}) - F(\vec{u})}{\epsilon}$.

So I have to solve 
$\frac{(D(u +\epsilon v)*(I(u+\epsilon v)) - (Du)(Iu))}{\epsilon}$, but I can't go on because I don't know how to do those products.

Any hint, or reference?

Comment: Is $*$ a matrix-vector product? Isn't $I\vec u=\vec u$? Is $D_1$ a matrix or some kind of derivative? If so, isn't $D_1*\vec u$ a vector and $I\vec u$ as well? How can you take the matrix-vector product of two vectors? Did you mean to write $F(\vec u) = (D_1\cdot \vec u)^T\cdot \vec u$? In that case $JF(\vec u)$ is just a $1$-by-$m$ matrix, right?

Comment: Hi, $D_1$ is a matricx of numbers. Yes, $I*u=u$, since $I$ is the identity. My problem is that I have to get that $JF$ is a matrix, not a vector

Comment: You should clear up what $(D_1*\vec u) * \vec u$ is supposed to mean, because $\vec u$ is a vector of lenght $m$ and $D_1*\vec u$ is a vector of some length (depending on the format of $D_1$). You cannot use the matrix-vector product to multiply two vector. Do you mean the dot product in that place?

Comment: $D_1$ is a $m$ square matrix. I know I can't multiply two vectors, but I've never seen it before.
How would you calculate the first limite I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're taking derivatives, $D_1$ is a confusing name for the matrix, so I will use $M$ instead.

The gradient of a matrix-valued function like $F=Muu^T$  with respect to a vector will be a 3rd order tensor.  So let's use index notation and calculate the gradient via the differential
$$\eqalign{
F_{ik} &= M_{ij}u_ju_k \cr\cr
dF_{ik} &= M_{ij}\,du_j\,u_k + M_{ij}u_j\,du_k \cr\cr
G_{ikp}=\frac{\partial F_{ik}}{\partial u_p}
  &= M_{ij}\,\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial u_p}\,u_k + M_{ij}u_j\,\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial u_p} \cr
  &= M_{ij}\,\delta_{jp}\,u_k + M_{ij}u_j\,\delta_{kp} \cr
  &= M_{ip}u_k + M_{ij}u_j\,\delta_{kp} \cr
}$$ 
Finally, you wanted to take the derivative in a particular direction $(v)$, which means
$$\eqalign{
dF_{ik}
 &= G_{ikp} (v_pd\epsilon) \cr
 &= (M_{ip}v_pu_k + M_{ij}u_j\,\delta_{kp}v_p)\,d\epsilon \cr\cr
\frac{dF}{d\epsilon} &= M(vu^T + uv^T) \cr
}$$